# Tascam ss-r250n playback and recording loop through same mixer

Tags: equipment

I just got a Tascam ss-r250n recorder & player. Is there anyway to turn off the output only when recording? I connect them both to my mixer but it creates a loop when recording. I guess the way it is intended is to just sit in between the mixer and the amplifier.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just mute the input channel that your Tascam output is plugged into?